# Need to disable clicks inside of div class but enable clicks for same class nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have one div class named expandInnerDivStyle  I need to disable clicks inside this div for this I'm doing like this

```
$(".expandInnerDivStyle").css({pointerEvents: "none"});
```

but In the div there may nested div with same class,Now I need to enable clicks for this nested div of same class.

Example of my scenario.

```
<div class="expandInnerDivStyle"> Disable this.
       <div class="parent abc"></div>  Disable this.
       <div clas="expandInnerDivStyle"> Need to enable clicks(Nested Class)
            <div class="child mno"></div> Enable this.
            <div class="child mpqr"></div> Enable this.
       </div>
       <div class="parent hhh"></div> Disable this.
</div>
```

Please can any help me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: If you have a `.parent` element, use that as a target.

Comment: give unique id's to the divs and select them that way

Comment: what is your exact problem ? , i think you can simply fix this like `.expandInnerDivStyle {pointerEvents: none; }`

Comment: On load of document I'm disabling click events.
I have Collapsible header div class named colExp for which the first child div class is expandInnerDivStyle.But again this expandInnerDivStyle class may contain nested Collapsible header of same calss colExp.
So now here come the problem.If there is nested collapsible header then that also disabled.

Comment: Attach the event to the inner `.expandInnerDivStyle` only, and stop the event propagation in the handler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('.expandInnerDivStyle > div*:not(.expandInnerDivStyle)').css({pointerEvents: "none"});
```